# CSS aligning a menu with submenus correctly- whole menu not centred

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a basis for a navigation bar. The menu can have multiple submenus within it. When a menu item with a submenu is clicked on the subMenu appears below. I have it mostly working except the nav doesnt take up the full width of the screen. When I try to center it the submenus break. I don't fully understand what I'm doing and I need some help understanding what is going on here and how to solve it. Thank you for any help given.

[The menu for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgzdN.png)

```css
nav {
    display: flex;
    font-weight: bold;
}

div {
    display: inline-block;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}
  
li:not(.subMenu){
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <div>
                <li id="About Me">About Me</li>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                    <li id="Test" class="subMenu">Test</li>
                    <li id="Test2" class="subMenu">Test2</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <li id="Projects">Projects</li>
            </div>
            <div>
                <li id="Temp">Temp</li>
            </div>
            <div>
                <li id="Helloooo">Helloooo</li>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                    <li id="Test44" class="subMenu">Test44</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

edit: removing "display: flex" or attempting to use justify-content or align-items appears to do nothing

Comment: Check if there is some padding in the header tags or even in the body. Padding sometimes increases/decreases the width and/or height of the parent element.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go...

The main problem was with positioning. If you want a child to have `position: absolute;`, you need to set `position: relative;` to the parent. Other than that, a little bit of CSS needs to be added.

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  font-weight: bold;
}

ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul > div {
  display: inline-block;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

li:not(.subMenu) {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.dropdown {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

#test,
#test2,
#test44 {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <div id="wrapper">
        <li id="About Me">About Me</li>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li id="Test" class="subMenu">Test</li>
          <li id="Test2" class="subMenu">Test2</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="wrapper">
        <li id="Projects">Projects</li>
      </div>
      <div id="wrapper">
        <li id="Temp">Temp</li>
      </div>
      <div id="wrapper">
        <li id="Helloooo">Helloooo</li>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li id="Test44" class="subMenu">Test44</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I used your answer and found (imo) a more succinct version of your answer and it worked perfectly. Wouldn't have figured it out without your help so will @ you in the answer

Comment: I will as soon as I have enough reputation to, I need 2 more, I do appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

You have it in flexbox so you need to specify position of container.
Something like

```
nav {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Justify-content doesn't appear to do anything and neither does align content. Even if  I remove diplay:flex the menu stays to the left

Comment: That's weird it worked for me. Here is working example.
https://codepen.io/test011001/pen/eYMaxbJ

Answer (score 0):

You need to give display flex to ul tag inside the nav tag because nav has only one child that is 
then give `justify-content: center` to  tag and it will center all the children

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Cervus camelopardalis for his answer which helped

Here is my solution, no changes to html but changed the css to:

```css
nav {
    display: flex;
    font-weight: bold;
}

ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}
  
li:not(.subMenu){
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.dropdown {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
}
```